# How can I filter a list view to allow a supervisor to only see the items created by their direct reports?

Tags: 2010, list-view, filter

I have a SharePoint 2010 list, and would like to create a view that would allow a supervisor to see items created by members of their team only.  I have already created a view that filters Created By = [Me].  I am hoping there is an equally simple way to filter for a supervisor based on the Created By field.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the caml Query to Look at the current usergroup

Look here https://christopherclementen.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/caml-query-membership-attribute/

Maybe that could help you out

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add more details on how you have your Supervisor-member hierarchy set?
Do you have different SharePoint user groups or AD groups for each team or do you have an Org chart set up in a list or term store? Do you have the Team value as a field in your list?

One way to do this is to use JQuery to filter out to hide stuff from different users, but then it would hiding data from the user on the page.

Based on how many teams you have, you create different views for each team.

You can also use item level permissions.

There is no simple view filter for this requirement using Created By.